# How can i center align two divs?

Tags: html, css

How can I align two inline divs so that the their adjacent edges are center?

So I'd like it to look like this:

```
    div1div1 div2div2
        div1 div2
div1div1div1 div2div2
```

I tried using inline block like like below but it is merely centering each line.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.left-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.right-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">div1div1</div>
  <div class="right-div">div2div2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">div1</div>
  <div class="right-div">div2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div">div1div1div1</div>
  <div class="right-div">div2div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/fkfmh7md/ to change the distance between divs, change 5px in padding:0 5px to any other value

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.container div.left {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">div1div1</div>
  <div>div2div2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">div1</div>
  <div>div2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">div1div1div1</div>
  <div>div2div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the divs are too far apart. Is there a way to control the distance in between each div?

Comment: @navig8tr try changing `width:45%` to 49% for left- and right-div

Comment: @navig8tr but this is not a good way to organise it. Use this instead https://jsfiddle.net/jfxee4jt/ if you want to change the distance between `left-div` and `right-div`, change 5px in `padding:0 5px; ` to any other value (`padding:0 5px;` 0 is for top and bottom paddings, 5 is for left and right paddings)

Comment: yeah that will be better

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not working well in IE compatibility mode and our site must still support IE8. Any suggestions?

Comment: My mistake... this seems to be working fine in IE8. It was IE7 i was having issues with.